# Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context, function with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, quosure

i have created a function with a plot result, but i have this error message:
Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

## Bad:

list(!!myquosure)

## Good:

dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)

when i erase the enquo() function, it plots but dont recognize the z argument for color
If anyone have an idea pls

```
f4 <- function(z){
  require("dplyr")
  require("lazyeval")
  require("reshape")
  z <- as_name(z)

plt <- mtcars %>% 
select_(~disp, ~hp, ~mpg, all_of(~z)) %>% 
group_by_at(vars(mpg, z)) %>%
summarise_all(sum) %>%
arrange_(~mpg)


plt1 <- gather(plt, key='variable', value = 'Monto', disp, hp) %>%
    mutate(catvar=paste(mpg, variable, sep='_'))
  
  
  z <- enquo(z)  
  
  
  fig <- plot_ly(plt1)
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x= ~catvar, y= ~Monto, color=!!z,
                           type = 'bar', colors= 'BrBG',
                           showlegend = TRUE,
                           hoverinfo = "text",
                           text = ~paste(catvar, '\n Monto:', Monto, 'MM USD \n ', z)) %>%
    layout(barmode = "stack") %>%
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title='MM USD', rangemode='tozero',side = 'left',  overlaying = "y2", title = 'MM de USD', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
  
  return(fig)
  
}

f4('carb')
```

Comment: Where is the function `f4` defined? Note that quosures aren't an R-thing, they are specific to the tidyverse packages. Functions that don't use the tidyverse back end can't use those features like `!!` and `{{ }}` and plotly is not a tidyverse package. You could maybe conditionally force some parts to be executed in a tidy environment but it's probably better to use the framework the package itself provides. for dynamic programming. So maybe use `color=get(z)` and leave out the `enquo()` step.

Comment: Thank you so much @MrFlick !!! it works with color=~get(z)